# Oracle 11g R2 Security patch installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11g R2 Free version in my laptop for development purpose, But i need to update the security patches given by Oracle. But while doing it it was taking me to a registration page where they are asking for Support Identifier. 
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Can you please put some screenshots ?

Comment: If you are using the OTN license you are not eligible to receive security patches. You only get them if you _buy_ a license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much into *licencing*, but - as far as I can tell - you get access to My Oracle Support (so that you could download patches, read additional documents, etc.) once you purchase (read: pay (a lot of) money) to Oracle because you started using their software in production.

For free versions, I'd say that you get quite a lot - regarding how much you paid for it (i.e. nothing at all), but shouldn't expect to get additional features as well.

If it is, as you said, for development purposes, why would you care about *security* patches? You don't trust yourself? :)

Therefore, in my opinion, you're out of luck.